# WCF Customised user authentication

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

I would like to create a login for my WCF service (over the internet) where a username and password submitted by the client (Windows Forms app) is compared to a username and password pair on my SQL server, if the two agree, the user is authenticated. Then, with respect to a some role that this user has on the SQL server he has access to certain functions on the service. And all communication needs to be end-to-end secure (message security).

Is there some simple solution to this problem? I have read 2 days worth of documentation and tutorials and still have not found a simple solution? wsHttpBinding works (windows accounts), however I believe what I am trying to do requires the custom validation. Also why do I require certificates to implement this?

Comment: How/where are you hosting the web service?

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2. Probably going to use IIS. The physical server is at the company's site.

Comment: Or as a Windows service. I'm not sure which one to pick since I am new to this. However the clients will all be Windows Forms applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom binding for customization.
I think if you host your service on IIS then the user can access the service using the default/app-pool credentials.
I this one is helpful for u. :)